# how to override ERE plugin in wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, overriding

I’m trying to add new functionality to the existing ERE plugin,

my plugin directory is  : E:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\wp-content\plugins\essential-real-estate
and

my theme directory is : E:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\wp-content\themes\mytheme

now I want to override [essential-real-estate](https://wordpress.org/plugins/essential-real-estate/) plugins for some files into my theme, files are below like,

E:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\wp-content\plugins\essential-real-estate\public\partials\property\class-ere-property.php

E:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\wp-content\plugins\essential-real-estate\includes\class-essential-real-estate.php

E:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\wp-content\plugins\essential-real-estate\essential-real-estate.php

E:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\wp-content\plugins\essential-real-estate\public\partials\property\class-ere-property.php

E:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\wp-content\plugins\essential-real-estate\public\assets\js\property\ere-property.min.js

how can I override these files even if I want to know with essential-real-estate main plugin and addon plugins how to override?

I have tried like
E:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\wp-content\themes\mytheme\ere\public\partials\property\class-ere-property.php but it's not working.

I have read the official document of this plugin using this [URL](https://plugins.g5plus.net/ere/faq/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20edit%20these%20files,%2Fpublic%2Ftemplates%2F%20subdirectory.&text=The%20copied%20file%20will%20now,real%2Destate%20default%20template%20file.),

its about only template overriding,

```
Essential-real-estate template files contain the markup and template structure for frontend of your site.

When you open these files, you will notice they all contain hooks that allow you to add/move content without needing to edit template files themselves. This method protects against upgrade issues, as the template files can be left completely untouched.

Template files can be found within the /essential-real-estate/public/templates/ directory:

You can edit these files in an upgrade-safe way using overrides. Copy it into a directory within your theme named /ere-templates/, keeping the same file structure but removing the /public/templates/ subdirectory.

Example: To override the contact agent in single property page, copy: wp-content/plugins/essential-real-estate/public/templates/single-property/contact-agent.php to wp-content/themes/yourtheme/ere-templates/single-property/contact-agent.php

The copied file will now override the essential-real-estate default template file.

Note: Do not edit these files within the core plugin itself as they are overwritten during the upgrade process and any customizations will be lost.
```

but there is an addon plugin of this main plugin, named "g5-ere"
i have checkewd this plugins template path

```
public function template_path() {
    return apply_filters( 'g5ere_template_path', 'g5plus/ere/' );
}
```

and i have create folder in my theme,
E:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\wp-content\themes\mytheme\g5plus\ere
its working overriding files,

same way i checked in essential-real-estate plugins template path,

```
public function template_path()
{
    return apply_filters('ere_template_path', 'ere-templates/');
}
```

I have tried like

E:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\wp-content\themes\mytheme\ere-templates\public\partials\property\class-ere-property.php

and

E:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\wp-content\themes\mytheme\ere\public\partials\property\class-ere-property.php

but it's not working.